# How to add csv file's data in newly created text file using javascript in highcharts

Tags: php, javascript, file, csv, highcharts

I am getting data from csv file and I am plotting its line chart. Now I want to create a new text file and want to place csv file's data in that new text file and it should have comma separated values. like if csv file has this content in it 1,1,2,3,4,5 then the new text file should also have this thing but it has to a file with .txt extension.

How should I do that?

```
$.get('testFile.csv', function(data) {
// Split the lines
var lines = data.split('\n');
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
var items = line.split(',');
var series = {
data: []
};
$.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
});
options.series.push(series);
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
function downloadWithName(uri, name) {
function eventFire(el, etype){
if (el.fireEvent) {
(el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
} else {
var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');                                                                          

evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);                                                                                

el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
}
}
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.download = name;
link.href = uri;
eventFire(link, "click");
}
downloadWithName("data:,options", "newtestFile.txt")
```

Comment: I would like to know how it is related with Highcharts? Obviously what is your purpose to dupliacte file by javascript?

Comment: We I think its not directly related to highcharts but I just need to duplicate data from the charts being created because maybe I might be needing some part of chart not the entire chart. The purpose of duplicating file is that I am passing that file to another function and in this example coincidentally the data is same but when i'll try to get partial data of a chart then the new file's data would differ.